# How can I correct this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm practising with JavaScript and hiding the image and the button. The footer keeps coming to the top of the page every time I execute the command. How can I correct this? I've tried many different options and I can't seem to get it to work right like `position: sticky, bottom:0;` for example.

I'm extremely new to this coding thing so I'm pretty sure I have no idea what I'm doing.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myButton").click(function(){
        
        $(".poem").show();
        $(".resize").show();
        $(".main-image").hide();
    });
    $(".resize").click(function(){
        
        $(".poem").hide();
        $(".resize").hide();
    })
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


.main-image {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}

.resize {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

footer {
    background-color: brown;
    border: solid;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}

.myButton {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>practice_overlay</title>
<link href="Overlay.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script_storage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="introduction">Lorem Ispum</p>
        <img class="main-image" src="Devry Web Design Intro Course/Pictures/crystal-tear-3.jpg">
        <div class="overlay-content">
        <button class="resize">X</button>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="poem">Lorem Ispum</p>
    </div>
    <button class="myButton">X</button>
    <footer>Lorem Ispum</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS grid - with the setup in the snippet below, you can "safely" work inside the `div.outer` part of the layout, without making the other parts of your page "jumping around" :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $(".poem").show();
    $(".resize").show();
    $(".main-image").hide();
  });

  $(".resize").click(function() {
    $(".poem").hide();
    $(".resize").hide();
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - 30px) 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background: gray;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {}

#image {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.myButton {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="introduction">Introduction</p>
      <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="small image" />
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <button class="resize">X</button>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
      <p class="poem">Lorem Ispum</p>
    </div>
    <button class="myButton">X</button>
  </div>
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```